# Apache Memory Corruption in Strace

Tags: php, apache

Unsure as to whether this is a SF or SO problem.

Very (very) busy LAMP servers in load balanced environment Apache 2.2.26 on Centos 5.10.

I'm trying to trace down a code or systems issue with hanging httpd processes.  These calls sit in W, "Sending Reply" status forever, the tcp connections remain in keepalive and the apache's timeout never fires. Eventually we accumulate enough hanging processes that I have to bounce the httpd process.

This is the end of an strace that seems to surround all of hung calls. I'm really unsure as to where to go next with this.  Seems Apache is trying to write out to the console, and I'm not sure if that's normal. But the malloc error definitely points to something wrong. Any help (even wild ideas) appreciated.

```
lstat("/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0

lstat("/tmp/promo.log", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14778558, ...}) = 

open("/tmp/promo.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 27

fstat(27, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14778558, ...}) = 0

lseek(27, 0, SEEK_CUR)                  = 0

lseek(27, 0, SEEK_CUR)                  = 0

write(27, "20140314065931 : cartitem::calcu"..., 68) = 68

close(27)                               = 0

open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)

writev(2, [{"*** glibc detected *** ", 23}, {"/usr/local/apache-2.2.26/bin/htt"..., 34}, {": ", 2}, {"double free or corruption (!prev"..., 33}, {": 0x", 4}, {"0000000005ebfb20", 16}, {" ***\n", 5}], 7) = 117

open("/usr/local/apache-2.2.26/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

open("/usr/lib64/tls/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

open("/usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

open("/usr/local/apache-2.2.26/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or 
directory)

open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 27

fstat(27, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=93743, ...}) = 0

mmap(NULL, 93743, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 27, 0) = 0x2ba82af8b000
close(27)                               = 0

open("/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY)  = 27

read(27, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\36`T8\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832

fstat(27, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=58400, ...}) = 0

open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)

writev(2, [{"*** glibc detected *** ", 23}, {"/usr/local/apache-2.2.26/bin/htt"..., 34}, {": ", 2}, {"malloc(): memory corruption", 27}, {": 0x", 4}, {"0000000005fc1e70", 16}, {" ***\n", 5}], 7) = 111

futex(0x2ba822f1dfc0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 9, NULL) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
--- SIGTERM (Terminated) @ 0 (0) ---

futex(0x2ba822f1b9e0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
--- SIGCONT (Continued) @ 0 (0) ---

futex(0x2ba822f1b9e0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL
```

Comment: Given the strace, this could be a stack or heap issue.

I assume you are using MPM prefork which is the default on Centos 5.x.  What are your MPM prefork settings and your overall memory configuration on the machine?  Are there other services running on the machine that dynamically consume memory (database servers etc...)?   Also, do you have 'ExtendedStatus on' and '/server-status' enabled for your _local_ interface?  That will help provide clues to what the rouge process is doing.

Comment: I can say that the addresses in the writev() lines reference heap area s in every strace I do (repeated steps several times). I verified this by looking at /proc/[PID]/maps.
We are running the prefork MPM 
StartServers         25
MinSpareServers      25
MaxSpareServers      25
MaxClients          512
MaxRequestsPerChild 1000

Machines are only running Apache/PHP, and have 6GB of memory in them, all on VMWare hosts w/ 256G, nowhere near oversubscribed.
I keep feeling like it's a code issue but not sure what my next steps are.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it was a physical memory error you would probably see it in your vm host logs.  My guess is that it is a rouge request or script error that is overloading memory.   Since you are monitoring the process status,  I am assuming you already have ExtendedStatus enabled.

Is it possible you have an application level error?  Perhaps a recursive function call that isn't popping.  Is there any pattern in the request paths on the hung processes?  You might consider logging PIDs and request data at the application level to see if there is a request being made that is triggering an error at that level.

Also, mod_log %D (request time in microseconds) along with the path may help you narrow down the culprit.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to debug it from a software but it's difficult on a production system. Thinking about adding a profiler to the code to output some logging. Thanks so much for chiming in!

Comment: valgrind may also help