# best way to find php memory leak?

Tags: php, apache, memory

I have an httpd server handling requests from about 1k active users, i have PHP memory limit set to 128MB.

I've been getting the following error in my logs since my user activity increased drastically

*** Error in `/usr/sbin/httpd': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x000055aae4918a9f ***

Backtrace:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7f5e4)[0x7fc15c81c5e4]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x82d00)[0x7fc15c81fd00]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x4c)[0x7fc15c82284c]
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(CRYPTO_realloc_clean+0x58)[0x7fc1574334d8]
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(BUF_MEM_grow_clean+0x70)[0x7fc1574dcc50]
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(+0x1193ad)[0x7fc1574de3ad]
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(BIO_write+0x6b)[0x7fc1574dd3cb]
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(+0x1419c2)[0x7fc1575069c2]
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(+0x141a8e)[0x7fc157506a8e]
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(+0x141e04)[0x7fc157506e04]
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(+0x141f8b)[0x7fc157506f8b]
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so(+0x259b3)[0x7fc14f9559b3]
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so(+0x20a42)[0x7fc14f950a42]
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so(+0x22701)[0x7fc14f952701]
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so(+0x1c624)[0x7fc14f94c624]
/usr/sbin/httpd(ap_run_fixups+0x40)[0x55aae3edbd70]
/usr/sbin/httpd(ap_process_request_internal+0x2da)[0x55aae3ede6fa]
/usr/sbin/httpd(ap_internal_redirect+0x40)[0x55aae3efb9c0]
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so(+0x4f6c)[0x7fc1549b6f6c]
/usr/sbin/httpd(ap_run_handler+0x40)[0x55aae3ee5a80]
/usr/sbin/httpd(ap_invoke_handler+0x69)[0x55aae3ee5fc9]
/usr/sbin/httpd(ap_process_async_request+0x1ea)[0x55aae3efc6aa]
/usr/sbin/httpd(+0x59a49)[0x55aae3ef8a49]
/usr/sbin/httpd(ap_run_process_connection+0x40)[0x55aae3eefa30]
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so(+0x685a)[0x7fc151df485a]
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so(+0x7f44)[0x7fc151df5f44]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7de5)[0x7fc15cd75de5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fc15c89bbad]
```

I am not sure if it's a script that's causing the memory leak or if I should just increase the memory limit from my php script. How can I find which script is causing the apache process to crash?

Is there anyway i can find the source of this problem without having to test every php script individually?

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? How is your question related to PHP?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/22425949/2191572 and https://serverfault.com/q/582322/255167

Comment: @Dave PHP could be the underlying cause but is only triggering it sporadically. OP needs to get better logs in place and narrow down the problem closest to the occurrence of the error.

Answer (score 1):

See this php extension **Memory Profiler** https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-memory-profiler.
 
You can easily dump information with different formats